# Replace URL (Text) in multiple files with sed (linux)

Tags: linux, sed

I need to replace all hardcoded urls in a Magento installation. How can I achieve that?

I tried to run following command but only get an error message:

```
grep -rl 'http://www.thisdomain.com/magento/1.4.2/' ./ | xargs sed -i 's^http://www.thisdomain.com/magento/1.4.2/^<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>^g'
```

Error: sed: 1: ".//design/frontend/defa ...": invalid command code .

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the `OS` and `sed` version? If you are on `OSX` you need to put empty quotes around `-i` like `sed -i '' ...` to make in-file changes

Comment: It was OSX and the '' after -i did the trick. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed -i -e 's;from;to;g' **/*.txt
```

Replease *from*, *to* and **.txt* according to your neads.